# Random Generator always generates number 0

Tags: java, arrays, random

I would like to know why the first number generated is always "0".

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean[] pack = new boolean[52];
    int[] cards = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < pack.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(pack[i] + " | ");         
    }
    System.out.println();

    Random give = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
       while (pack[cards[i]])
            cards[i] = give.nextInt(5);  

       pack[cards[i]] = true;                 
       System.out.println(cards[i]);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pack.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(pack[i] + " | ");         
    }     
}
```

Comment: javascript != java

Comment: Additionally, please format your code - it's *really* hard to read at the moment. (It would also help if you'd make it a *complete* program. You're so close, with a `main` method - but just including the class declaration and imports would help us to just copy, paste, compile and run.)

Comment: This `give.nextInt(5)`, do you mean `give.nextInt(pack.length)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `pack(cards[i])` is always false on the first iteration. The solution could be implementing a `do-while` instead a `while`.

Check this:

### Main:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class hw {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

            boolean[] pack = new boolean[52];
            int[] cards = new int[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < pack.length - 1; i++) 
            {
                System.out.print(pack[i] + " | ");         
            }

            System.out.println();

            Random give = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
                do
                {
                    cards[i] = give.nextInt(5); 
                }
                while ( pack[cards[i]] );

                pack[cards[i]] = true;                 
                System.out.println(cards[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < pack.length - 1; i++) 
            {
                System.out.print(pack[i] + " | ");         
            }     
       }

}
```

### Output:

> false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false |
>
> 4
>
> 3
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> true | true | true | true | true | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false | false |

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will definitely review the code with the solution you gave me